# Staggering around/about (on) the roof

Tags: word-choice, difference

> Last time I checked, the drunk man was still staggering around/about (on) the roof.

1. I have seen both "around" and "about" used. Are they completely interchangeable in this context? Which is more common?
2. Should "on" be included or doesn't it matter? What is more common/correct - with or without "on"?

Answer (score 1):

With *on*, they are interchangeable.

*Staggering around the roof* suggests to me that the man was going in a circle round the circumference of the roof (yes, I know roofs are usually rectangular, but you see what I mean).